# How would I convert flash to html5 web animation

Tags: flash, html5-canvas

On this page : http://dev.jsp.com/, there is a flash animation that loads external images, is there a HTML5 way I can take the .swf and perhaps get a head start on trying to make it a HTML5 version?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on the content/complexity of the animation.

If it's complex, you could use a jsfl script to export a spritesheet you could playback in html, but if it's simple enough(no code, complex gradients and filters), you can give [**Google Swiffy**](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) a go.

Comment: I used google swiffy, and I got the shapes and animation, except the loading of the external images, not sure how to get them random in each square..

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have problems when converting .fla files that use external data. Could you save a version of that file and embed the assets just for the conversion ? Maybe that will work better. Another thing that comes to mind is exporting an uncompressed quicktime file from flash (File > Export > Export Movie (quicktime)) as it picks up actionscript as well, and then use something like [avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) to get individual frames and maybe some a tool for packing data, not sure...might get a bit cumbersome this way.